# CSharp -> Property getter expression does not work with Condition

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I've got the following Code:

```
    public static Func<object, string> GetPropGetter(Type objectType, string propertyName)
    {
        ParameterExpression paramExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "value");

        Expression e = Expression.Convert(paramExpression, objectType);

        foreach (var name in propertyName.Split('.'))
        {
            e = Expression.Property(e, name);
        }

        Expression propertyGetterExpression = Expression.Call(e, typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes));

        Func<object, string> result =
            Expression.Lambda<Func<object, string>>(propertyGetterExpression, paramExpression).Compile();

        return result;
    }
```

This works if the Property is not null. For this check I changed the Code to:

```
    public static Func<object, string> GetPropGetter(Type objectType, string propertyName)
    {
        ParameterExpression paramExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "value");

        Expression e = Expression.Convert(paramExpression, objectType);

        foreach (var name in propertyName.Split('.'))
        {
            e = Expression.Property(e, name);
        }

        Expression propertyGetterExpression = Expression.IfThenElse(Expression.Equal(Expression.Default((e as MemberExpression).Type), e), Expression.Constant(""), Expression.Call(e, typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes)));


        Func<object, string> result =
            Expression.Lambda<Func<object, string>>(propertyGetterExpression, paramExpression).Compile();

        return result;         
    }
```

Now I got the Exception: ArgumentException, the Expression of Type void could not be used for the return value of string!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may not be the *only* thing that you need to do, but I think you want to use [`Expression.Condition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.condition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rather than `Expression.IfThenElse`.

Currently you've got the equivalent of:

```
if (condition) {
    default(...);
} else {
    property-getters
}
```

without any return. (As noted in the documentation, the overall type of the expression returned by `IfThenElse` is `Void`.)

You really want:

```
return condition ? default(...) : property-getters;
```

The latter is what `Expression.Condition` represents.

Comment: If this question & answer would have come a day sooner, I wouldn't be mad on wasting almost a whole day trying to figure this out... Is there a simple way of returning a result from an `IfThenElse`, other than playing with lables?

Comment: I think, @Jon Skeet is right about using Expression.Condition instead.